# How to get SiteDefinition.Current in a Add-On AfterInstall event

Tags: c#, episerver

We are trying to access `SiteDefinition.Current` at the time of `AfterInstall()`. What we need is `SiteUrl` and `Id` but it seems that at the time of this event they are not available.

How can we postpone the calling of `AfterInstall` or otherwise, could we attach an event listener in `AfterInstall` that can later in the pipeline provide us the data and how?

The class is decorated like this:

```
[InitializableModule]
[ModuleDependency(typeof(EPiServer.Packaging.PackageInitializer))]
public class ModulePackageInitializer : PackageInitializer
```

***UPDATE***
During the AfterInstall event the current SiteDefinition is not set. This means that you have to get the SiteDefinition Repositories instead:

```
var siteDefinitionRepository = 
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<SiteDefinitionRepository>();
var siteDefinitions = siteDefinitionRepository.List().ToList();
```

Then iterate and get the values.

Comment: It seems like `SiteDefinition.Current` is set in `EPiServer.Enterprise.Internal.DefaultSiteContentInitialization`. Would it be possible to set it as module dependency, or alternatively, create a separat initialization module (which has `DefaultSiteContentInitialization` as dependency), which triggers an event, that your package initializer is hooked up to?

Comment: Thank you Andreas. Were moving that direction when the solution mentioned in my update

Comment: When doing this, please ensure your add-on works in multisite environments as well!